# Are imported, machine slaughtered meats served to pilgrims in Mecca?

Tags: nutrition, islam, saudi-arabia

I recently received this message on whatsapp:

> A warning to those Intending to perform Umrah or Hajj
>
> Mufti Abdullah Nana, the founding member of the Halal Advocates of
>   America, says:
>
> "I can personally verify that machine slaughtered chicken, meat not
>   slaughtered by a Muslim, & doubtful meat is imported into Saudi
>   Arabia.
>
> The senior body of scholars in Saudi Arabia (the Hay'ah Kibaril Ulama)
>   has formally issued a 50 page fatwa that all imported meat is haram.
>
> It is a major travesty and perhaps a conspiracy that millions of
>   Muslims that visit Makkah/Madinah every year are eating haram/doubtful
>   food”
>
> There are local hand slaughter suppliers, but only a small percentage.
>
> 90% of fast food chains (McDondalds, KFC etc) including Al-Baik use
>   imported meat.
>
> For reference, I have translated the detailed fatwa of the Hay'ah
>   Kibaril Ulama (Body of Senior Scholars) as part of the following
>   book:"
>
> Mufti Taqi Uthmanis DBs Research including the above fatwa :
>
> https://attahawi.files.wordpress.com/2010/12/mufti-taqi-uthmani-legal-rulings-on-slaughtered-animals.pdf
>
> Please Download & Share !

But I can't verify or disprove this, Snopes doesn't seem to have anything, and the only website I can find associated with Mufti Nana is [this](http://halaladvocates.net/site/) which doesn't mention it.

**Are imported, machine slaughtered meats served to pilgrims in Mecca?**

Comment: Recommendations By Shaykh (Mufti) Taqi Usmani here-http://zakir.me.uk/salaf/Islamic-rulings-for-slaughtering-animals-By-Shaykh-Mufti-Taqi-Usmani-HA.pdf state that "Muslim countries should increase their animal stock so that they don't have to import meat from nonMuslim countries" since the visits to current Halal certified facilities in non-Muslim countries show that  they actually do not fulfill the requirements of slaughtering according to Muslim law i.e. slaughtering by Muslims or People of the book, reciting the name of  their god Allah during slaughter, cutting the required vessels etc.

Comment: According to his [twitter feed](https://twitter.com/muftiabdullah/status/417481500201082880), the quote seem valid. Looking at the comments, the original claim has little evidence to support it, but wasn't completely disproved either.